# Open multiport in HTTPD.conf: Operation Timedout

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf, aws-security-group

I have installed httpd in AWS EC2 linux machine. In httpd.conf file, in /etc/httpd/conf path, I have added the following 2 blocks:

Listen 8080

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

The page opens for port 80 but not for 8080. I get "Operation timedout" .I have saved and restarted HTTPD server
I have opened custom tcp port for 8080 in the SG.